# Como eu carrego/salvo o item selecionado do ComboBox embutido em um ListView em WPF

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml

Eu não posso simplesmente colocar o atributo x:Name no ComboBox, porque há mais de um. Eu também não sei como pegar um ComboBox específico no code-behind e usar a propriedade Text.
Aqui está uma versão simplificada do meu arquivo XAML:

```
<Page
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <!-- its Page because i'm using Kaxaml -->
  <Page.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="PropertyData" XPath="/properties">
                <x:XData>
                <!-- This is actually in an external xml file -->
                    <properties xmlns="">
                        <property name="some property">
                            <item value="5"  />
                            <item value="10"  />
                            <item value="15"  />
                            <item value="20"  />
                        </property>
                        <property name="other property">
                            <item value="5"  />
                            <item value="10"  />
                            <item value="15"  />
                            <item value="20"  />
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                </x:XData>
            </XmlDataProvider>
  </Page.Resources>
  <ListView  DataContext="{StaticResource PropertyData}" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=property}">
    <ListView.View>
      <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Property" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=@name}" />
        <GridViewColumn Header="Value">
          <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <ComboBox Width="100" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=item}"  DisplayMemberPath="@value"></ComboBox>
            </DataTemplate>
          </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
      </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
  </ListView>
</Page>
```

Ok, se você souber responder essa, você ganha o gênio badge. Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Vc tem algum motivo para usar `XmlDataProvider`?  Já pensou em usar padrão MVVM e carregar os dados internamente para popular os combos?